# Trying to set up a website on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: server

Today I've been trying to setup a website on my computer running Ubuntu Server 16.04. I'm trying to install Ghost on it to run my blog. I also bought a domain name (Namecheap). I've been searching google for a long time but didn't find answers on what to do and quite frankly, I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for.

Now, my question is basically; what do I have to setup on my server computer so that the website runs on the domain I bought?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, you're going to want to setup your webserver. I'm not entirely familiar with how ghost works, but look at a tutorial like [this DigitalOcean one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-blog-with-ghost-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) which will tell you what to do. Ghost is a type of content platform that runs *on top* of a webserver, which is actually serving your pages. You need to install a webserver as well. This tutorial recommends nginx, which is a common and well-supported web server that a lot of people use.

You'll also need to setup your domain to point to your server. This part kind of depends on your specific setup. Figure out your server's public IP address by running this command:

```
wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -
```

You need to make your domain forward to that address. This generally involves adding DNS 'A' records for '' and 'www.' that point to your public IP. If your server is behind a router, you might also have to enable port forwarding.